# API driven symfony2 project

Tags: api, symfony, fosrestbundle

Im trying to create an API driven project in symfony2 using `FOSRestBundle`.

I have an `APIController` with an action `getDataAction().`

This works perfectly when i send requests from some external application.I get a JSON encoded data as expected.

But i'll be needing that data in the same application as well(i.e. some other controller within the same application).

Which is an appropriate method of doing this?

- creating object of the `APIController` and then calling required action on it.
  OR
- or sending a CURL request from the other controller to `getDataAction()` of the `APIController` to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can get data from an APIController by using **[route forwarding](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/controller.html#forwarding)** . By using this you can the use any action in your controller. No need for the *curl* or separate controller object. some thing like this :

```
 $details = $this->forward('acmeRestBundle:API:getData',array('_format'=>'json'));
```

That will return the result-set from that action.May be like this :

```
  content":protected]=>
  string(107181) "{}"
  ["version":protected]=>
  string(3) "1.0"
  ["statusCode":protected]=>
  int(200)
  ["statusText":protected]=>
  string(2) "OK"
  ["charset":protected]=>
  NULL
```

Comment: i know about route forwarding. But what i want to know is which is the correct method?? . And is making curl request internally the correct approach

Comment: If you need to resort to Curl to call a method in your application, it means you have serious architectural problems in your code. You should outsource whatever business logic you have in your controller to services. Controllers should only deal with http , not how datas are managed.

Comment: i do not need to resort to curl. i just wanted to know is it the correct approach and from your answer i think it is NOT! So should i opt for route forwarding?

Comment: In symfony2 perspective url forwarding is the best method, I think.